# Unable to run (R not resolved) for SlidingLayer Library

Tags: android, user-interface, android-sliding, sliding-window

I am trying to run the [SlidingLayerSample - github](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib) code. I downloaded the entire repository (including folder 'Library' & 'SlidingLayerSample') and imported them to eclipse.

[image]

Then I added 'Library' as a "library" for the sample in eclipse.

[image]

The problem "R cannot be resolved..." just does not go away. I have cleaned the project and reopened Eclipse several times.

[image]

**I guess the question is - Has anyone tried running this sample? or can someone try this quick please???  Thanks a lot for this.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You have error in **xml** `layout` try to correct that and save it then automatically `R.java` will generate other wise try to clean project

```
Projects>Clean>select your project
```